# get css pseudo-element content with python or selenium

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, pseudo-element

I am working with Selenium and Python to automate a web service. I need to extract the text "test" from below, but am having difficulty figuring out how, or even if this is possible in selenium, or with a python library.

```
<label class="checkbox" for="checkbox1"data reactid=".0.1.0.1.$modal.$=10.0.1:1.5.1">
    before::
    "test"    
    ::after
</label>
```

Basically there is a checkbox and next to the checkbox displays the text in the pseudo-element. I am able to click on the checkbox, but I need to display the text to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.text` should handle that:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("label.checkbox").text
```

Comment: Thanks @alecxe! I've been reading a lot of your posts to help me do this. That works!